# Mathematica: How to check if no argument is supplied to a function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How to check if no argument is supplied to a function?

For example, if I have:

```
  f[x_Integer]:=1
  f[x_]:=Message[errm::err, x]
```

and I call f with no argument:

```
   f[]
```

'nothing happens', I want to force a specific (error-)condition.

( Background: I am making MUnit tests for packages and OO-System classes. )

Comment: As far as I understand it functions in mathematica are "bound" to their parameters, in the sense that if you define f(a) , f is still undefined.

Comment: @Gleno There are no functions in Mathematica (except possibly pure and compiled functions). What look like function definitions are global rules. What you probably meant is that the existence of a global rule for pattern `f[something]` does not imply the existence of another global rule for plain `f` - which is true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This?

```
f[x_Integer] := 1
f[x_] := Message[errm::err, x]
f[] := Message[errm::err]
```

Comment: Deleted my answer ... one minute late :)

Comment: @belisarius luck on my part :)

Comment: +1. Both in the @ndroock1's code and here `Null` is returned on error. This does not seem (to me) generally appropriate. The output must somehow be meaningful, even on errors. In the symbolic environment, it is common to use the trick such as `f[]:="nothing"/;Message[errm::err]`, to make `f[]` both return a message and evaluate to itself. In the programming environment, it is common to issue an error message and return `$Failed`, like `f[]:= (Message[errm::err];$Failed)`. Sometimes (for inner functions say) exceptions are more appropriate. Which one to choose depends on the context.

Answer (score 11):

As an alternative to explicitly listing the zero-args possibility, you can do

```
f[x_Integer] := 1
f[args___] := (Message[errm::err, {args}];$Failed);
```

which would also catch the error cases of several passed arguments (assuming that it is an error).